# Issue in json request response, getting blank response

Tags: ios, web-services, request, browser, response

I am stuck with an issue in simple request response in iOS, I am getting blank response in request a url with one post parameter, where **the url as it is perfectly working in android and webbrowser**

Friends in detail, I have to call

`http://example.com/GetCountries`

with below http post params

```
"key"="Abcd1234"
```

it is working before, but from last few days it is not working, if I check NSError it is showing me **The network connection was lost.**

and one more thing noticeable here is same server code is on different url and it is working fine, and that url you can test as below

`http://example.com/GetCountries`

with below http post params

```
"key"="Abcd1234"
```

Here is the dropbox link for testing ios source code and also the folder contains **Web services test.htm** file to test that same url with same post parameter working in browser but not in ios device.

Testing code:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/lqrl5b95j2s54mm/Testing.zip?token_hash=AAFgoNfUpQ4FkeswnPdGiMVzdMtSM6js9KySJm_OH6lZXQ&dl=1

thank you

Comment: Write a little demo app that demonstrates the problem, then upload it to DropBox. Update the question and people will look at it then.

Comment: @DavidH you are right I should upload it before asking here, but currently I cant bcz i have not my mac with me,sry if possible plz manage it with any of ur project and just change url of any working project,sorry again for this

Comment: It does nothing in a web browser. If you can craft a curl command that works, that would help.

Comment: I have updated the question and add dropbox url of sample source code. Thanks

Comment: Parker, if at all possible can you dump the NSURLRequest - the body and the headers. While using this library has let you proceed, it does not answer the question of why what appears to be a properly formatted form does not work. You can grab the log lines from the code I posted earlier. Or post what your revised method looks like now and I'll do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I have used ASIHTTP Library and my problem is solved***

Answer (score 1):

So I could not get the form per se to work but was able to recraft it to work. Note a few things:

- you should convert to ARC!
- you need a strong reference to the connection so you can release it later on (and not in a delegate method!)
- you need the delegate connectionSucceeded method (to record response whatever!)

CODE:

```
- (void)asynchronousRequest
{
    [activity startAnimating];

    NSString *requesturl = lblURL.text;
    NSLog(@"requesturl=%@", requesturl);
    NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:requesturl];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [request setURL:theURL];
    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:60.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"key=%@", [self URLencodedString:@"Abcd1234"]];
    NSLog(@"BODY: %@", str);
    NSData *body = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"URL : %@", requesturl);
    NSLog(@"REQ : %@", request);

    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", [body length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];


    NSLog(@"AllFields : %@", [request allHTTPHeaderFields]);
    NSLog(@"HTTPBody : %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request HTTPBody] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    NSLog(@"HTTPMethod : %@", [request HTTPMethod]);

    self.activeDownload = [NSMutableData data];

    conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    assert(conn);
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    assert([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]);
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response; 
    NSLog(@"GOT %d", [httpResponse statusCode]);

}
- (NSString *)URLencodedString:(NSString *)s
{
    CFStringRef str = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)s,  NULL,  (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&;=+$,/?%#[]",  kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    NSString *newString = [(NSString *)str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
    if(str) CFRelease(str);
    return newString;
}
```

EDIT: Modified Code that still didn't work:

```
- (void)asynchronousRequest
{

    [activity startAnimating];

    NSString *boundary = @"1010101010"; // DFH no need for the leading '--'
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];


    NSMutableDictionary *postVariables = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [postVariables setValue:@"Abcd1234" forKey:@"key"];


    NSString *requesturl = lblURL.text;

    NSMutableString *myStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    NSString *str;

    // DFH - strategy is to have each line append its own terminating newline/return
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary]; // DFH initial boundary
    [myStr appendString:str];


    NSArray *formKeys = [postVariables allKeys];
    for (int i = 0; i < [formKeys count]; i++) {
        str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n%@\r\n",[formKeys objectAtIndex:i],[postVariables valueForKey:[formKeys objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [myStr appendString:str];

        str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary]; // DFH mid or terminating boundary
        [myStr appendString:str];
    }
    NSLog(@"BODY: %@", myStr);
    NSData *body = [myStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    requesturl = [self encodeStringForURL:requesturl];
    NSLog(@"requesturl=%@", requesturl);

    NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:requesturl];

    self.activeDownload = [NSMutableData data];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:theURL];
    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:60.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"]; // DFH you add addValue, I always use setValue

    NSLog(@"URL : %@", requesturl);
    NSLog(@"REQ : %@", request);
    NSLog(@"ContentType \"%@\"", contentType);

    if(body)
    {
        [request setHTTPBody:body];
    }
    NSLog(@"AllFields : %@", [request allHTTPHeaderFields]);
    NSLog(@"HTTPBody : %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request HTTPBody] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    NSLog(@"HTTPMethod : %@", [request HTTPMethod]);

    conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    assert(conn);
}
```

Comment: thank you that's a useful code and works fine, but in my other webservice where I posting image to server I must use multipart/form-data, and the same problem of blank response happen again. I feel the whole problem is only because of content-type multipart/form-data. If you can check for same post content with multipart/form-data then that will be really appreciated.

Comment: I spent an hour or more trying to get it to work with the original code you had. Your original code is not properly formatting the form, but even so I could never get anything but a disconnect as you observed. I'm a little unsure of the code since I don't use that myself but I'll post what I did. If you can get it to work using "curl" it would help. There are some example posts on SO that showed using the multipart form, and I looked at the standard too - no help.

Comment: I just appended the modified code with "// DFH" notation around changes I made. Look at: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4 and http://chxo.com/be2/20050724_93bf.html . Also the line containing boundary, the second link says use a comma not a ';'.